# How to detect incoming request coming from another website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having two asp.net websites (say website1 and website2). There is a requirement of redirecting users from one website to the other based on some user action. Is there are a way to detect if incoming request is coming from website1 to website2.
I was trying to make the request with a quesrystring from website1, but the querystring is not recognized by website2.

To add more details to this question:
**In Website1:**

```
protected void Button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Response.Redirect ( "http://website2.com/Home.aspx?empid=1" );
}
```

**In website2 home.aspx:**

```
protected void page_init ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string str=Request.QueryString ["empid"]; // str is coming as 'null'. 
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Saikat

Comment: What is the querystring? What do you mean by 'not recognized'? Does website2 knows what requestparameters to check in the querystring? etc. etc... Showing some code would help.

Comment: The situation here: in website1, I am having Response.Redirect("http://website2/a.aspx?empid=1") and I need to get "empid=1" from the request. Request.QueryString is coming as null. website2 is aware of the the queryparameters.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `Request.UrlReferrer` in your website2 page.

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null) {
    variable = Request.UrlReferrer.toString();
}

if (variable.Contains("website1")) {
    // coming from website1
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, Request.UrlReferrer will give me the url from where the request is coming from. The situation here: in website1, I am having Response.Redirect("http://website2/a.aspx?empid=1") and I need to get "empid=1" from the request.

Comment: I was responding to your unedited question: `a way to detect if incoming request is coming from website1 to website2`. After the edit it is clear that you are looking to extract the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

> In Website1:
>
> ```
> protected void Button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e ) { 
>    Response.Redirect ( "http://website2.com/Home.aspx?empid=1" ); 
> }
> ```
>
> In website2 home.aspx:
>
> ```
> protected void page_init ( object sender, EventArgs e ) { 
>     string str=Request.QueryString ["emp"]; // str is coming as 'null'. 
> }
> ```

You're sending empid in the querystring, and you are reading `Request.QueryString ["emp"]`

Change one of both to match the other.

Comment: Aah!! my bad. That was a typo here, I am actually checking ["empid"] only at both the places.

Answer (score 0):

You send the `empid` as a request variable, and you search for `emp` variable. You should change the method on the website 2:

```
protected void page_init ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string str=Request.QueryString ["empid"]; 
}
```

You could use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString) post as a reference.

Hope I helped!